# Display original and duplicate data from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with the following columns:

- `id`
- `name`
- `mail`

There is lot of data in this table and chances of duplicate data is very high.

I want to display original data row and duplicate data row one after other so that user can delete duplicate data on clicking delete button.

Comment: maybe GROUP BY email?

Comment: so wat is the issue?

Comment: did you tried something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you select the data and only order them by email address, the original and the duplicates will come together. The rest of the logic can be covered in PHP too.

Comment: Seems to be comment more.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no provision to detect original and dubplicate records in my sql. group by can give u dublicate entry of same record if any there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by mail having count(id) > 1` in your select query to find out the records which are duplicate. Then you can use this query result as sub query and find out all records which are duplicate and order them base on mail.